# MAC Address null in sony xperia

Tags: android, mac-address, sony

I am getting null on  wimanager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress() in sony xperia. I have tested in dell, samsung and LG,all are returning MAC address. But in case of Sony xperia it is null. Why???

Comment: have you tried it with sim in device?

Comment: Sony xperia tested with sim also.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get this "answer" as a comment - but it seems my rep are too low so I risk reducing it even further :) .

I hate to say: "It works for me" - but it does, on my Xperia Active.
This snippet of code:

```
            WifiManager wfm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            String kalle = wfm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
            System.out.println("MAC Addr:" + kalle);
```

Gives this output:
:
03-28 11:09:50.458: I/System.out(5053): MAC Addr:8c:64:22:2f:bd:c2
:
Is WiFi properly enabled ? Is the phone connected to wifi ? If all this is yes – I think it would be of great assistance to Sony trouble shooters if you could provide following information in this thread:

Which kind of Xperia phone is it you have. There are a lot of Xperia phones out there. 
What phone software do you have on your sample of the phone ? (Settings -> About phone -> Version)

Kind regards
  /Johan